# After replacing a 1-gang electrical box with a 3-gang box, am I allowed use the same 1-gang wallplate and drywall over the rest of the box?

Tags: electrical

I need to increase the cu/in (inner space) of a switch.
So I'll switch from 1 gang to 3 gang, and place the switch back in.

After replacing a 1-gang electrical box with a 3-gang box, am I allowed use the same 1-gang wallplate and drywall over the rest of the box?

Basically It would cover with drywall, the other 2 "gangs".
(I would have to recess it in more, and use longer screws)

Comment: You certainly cannot use just drywall for that. There are companies that make a "mud ring" to reduce a 3-gang box to a 1-gang opening [like this](https://www.lightingsupply.com/garvin-gbsd-3150.aspx?gclid=CjwKCAjw4pT1BRBUEiwAm5QuR4dz0R8KC6UyS_uKwlO83Zs1Ii8Iz_FkwiWadywjViaP2oIVF0Bz0xoCugwQAvD_BwE), but they are expensive. I also don't know what code says about them.

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do this ? Why do you need such a big box ?

Comment: @MosheKatz -- that's an answer I'd vote for. Even better if you had chapter and verse from the NEC.

Comment: And fwiw, 2 gang to 1 gang mudrings are readily available and way cheaper than the item linked above.

Comment: Even if you increase the cu" of the box, the wires/connections still have to be accessible . Just leave the box open and get a three gang cover with one switch position.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I'm waiting for someone else to quote NEC, since I actually want to do a 2-gang to 1-gang reduction myself (of an existing box) if it's allowed.

Comment: @MosheKatz If you need to know something and **you have done the research but have still not found the answer**  then you should post it as its own stand alone question. Have you looked up the code, have you done any research ? Take the tour. https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Why are you using an expensive 3-gang switch box? Just use a deep 4/S box with a plaster ring if you need space...

Comment: @AlaskaMan If I saw my question and this one, I would close mine as a duplicate of this one. And after ThreePhaseEel's answer to this one I don't need to ask mine.

Answer (score 5):

### No, you can't box a box in like that!

When you have a multigang box, all the innards need to be accessible without removing *any* building finish, as per NEC 314.29, so that the next bloke who services the thing can get at all the stuff inside.  Your choices are to either use a 3-gang to 1-gang mudring (as was linked in the comments), or to use a 3-gang cover that has blank spaces (i.e. no switch or receptacle openings) in the other gangs.